Why does Rick Astley play a prominent role in "I Woke Up A Vampire"?
The series I Woke Up A Vampire has frequent references to the work of Rick Astley. Most notably, at the end of the first season, Carmie and the other kids perform a cover of "Never Gonna Give You Up," after which Rick Astley (possibly played by the actual Rick Astley) does a video call to reveal that he is in fact a vampire. At the end of the second season, Carmie quotes "Never Gonna Give You Up," and the Shapeshifter claims to have invented the Rickroll.
Is there any significance to the prominence of Rick Astley here? For instance, did he finance the show, or is there some symbolic significance to the frequent mentions of him?

Maybe the script writer is a fan?

I'm pretty sure the gag is that they got him as a cameo (as a vampire) and then decided to foreshadow that; https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=E6ShTqANEcA
